# Implementing Canonical URLs

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url

I have a confusion in implementing canonical URLs;

Client has shared a set of URLs like;

```
http://example.com/eg/
http://example.com/eg/index?32312323
http://example.com/eg/index?54545545
http://example.com/eg/index?45554455
```

What I did to make them canonical I have added below tag on each of the above page header;

```
<link href="http://example.com/eg/" rel="canonical">
```

I have following questions:

1. Do implementation is right?
2. If yes; google will take care of rest like content duplication issue etc?
3. Any further improvement or any better alternative?

Please do let me know if I am not clear

Thanks

Comment: A canonical tag is designed to indicate which is the original content in a case where there is duplicate content. For that reason, the canonical tag must point to the original always.

Comment: Its means implementation is correct? as client wanted to refer everything to `<link href="http://example.com/eg/" rel="canonical">`

Comment: That would be an incorrect implementation - completely. At the very least, the page should refer to itself. If you have duplicate content, the canonical tag should refer to the original. It should never refer to another page that is completely different.

Comment: @closetnoc all of the pages are the same there is one main page i.e. `http://example.com/eg/`

Comment: Okay. I got it. That makes sense. Ignore what I said. ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: The answer from @Mike is correct giving what you have told me.

Comment: I am not sure why I did not see it the way you intended it. Working off of 3.5 hours sleep - but that cannot be it - can it?? Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the following URL's output *exactly* the same code:

```
http://example.com/eg/
http://example.com/eg/index?32312323
http://example.com/eg/index?54545545
http://example.com/eg/index?45554455
```

And of all the URLs, you want to see the following URL in search engines:

```
http://example.com/eg/
```

then edit your scripts so that this line:

```
<link href="http://example.com/eg/" rel="canonical">
```

is between `<head>` and `</head>` in the code produced from each of these URLs:

```
http://example.com/eg/index?32312323
http://example.com/eg/index?54545545
http://example.com/eg/index?45554455
```

By adding that tag, you declared the code in the above three URLs an exact copy of the code in this URL:

```
http://example.com/eg/
```

You don't need to declare canonical inside:

```
http://example.com/eg/
```

because you designated that URL as the original content URL.

Comment: You mean there is no need to add `<link href="http://example.com/eg/" rel="canonical">` on `http://example.com/eg/` as its original page right?

Comment: That's right. Doing so will confuse the heck out of google because the href in the link tag points to the URL of the original copy of all the copies of the page. Never declare the original copy as a copied page.

Comment: **Google will not confuse if you place canonical link tag on original page as well.** I disagree with mike.

Comment: @Goyllo do you have any ref. for this. That will be helpful. Thanks